# Java REST api for determining the rally permissions for user

Tags: java, rest, rally

I am using the below REST API for rally to determine the user permission for a specific project..

user    start=1&pagesize=200&fetch=UserName%2CSubscription%2CDisplayName%2CRole%2CUser%2CW orkspacePermission%2CProjectPermissions%2CUserPermissions&order=ObjectID&query=%28UserName+%3D+xxx1%40xx.com%29&workspace=%2Fworkspace%2F14174856157&project=https%3A%2F%2Frally1.rallydev.com%2Fslm%2Fwebservice%2Fv2.0%2Fproject%2F39185397159&projectScopeUp=false&projectScopeDown=true

```
QueryRequest userRequest = new QueryRequest("User");
    userRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("UserName", "Subscription", "DisplayName", "Role", "User", "WorkspacePermission", "ProjectPermissions", "UserPermissions"));
    userRequest.setWorkspace(testCase.getWorkspaceRef());
    //userRequest.setWorkspace("Testing");
    userRequest.setProject(testCase.getProjectRef());
    //userRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("UserName", "=", email).and(new QueryFilter("role", ">=", "Team Member")));
    userRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("UserName", "=", email));

    QueryResponse userQueryResponse = rally.query(userRequest);




{
    "QueryResult":
    {
        "_rallyAPIMajor": "2",
        "_rallyAPIMinor": "0",
        "Errors":
        [
        ],
        "Warnings":
        [
        ],
        "TotalResultCount": 1,
        "StartIndex": 1,
        "PageSize": 200,
        "Results":
        [
            {
                "_rallyAPIMajor": "2",
                "_rallyAPIMinor": "0",
                "_ref": "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/user/35078187498",
                "_refObjectUUID": "489fc643-8b19-4952-ae3c-20192e22912a",
                "_objectVersion": "178",
                "_refObjectName": "xx ",
                "DisplayName": null,
                "Role": "Team Member",
                "UserName": "xxxx@xxx.com",
                "_type": "User"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

unfortunately i am not able to get the permissions and other details i have requested from the API..is there something wrong about my query ?

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: my bad i saved it before i could insert the code.

Comment: Does Rally expose a REST API to get those details?   If yes, then you should review their docs to see why yours is wrong.  If not, how did you ever expect this to work?

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to make a request to the UserPermissions collection for whatever user you are trying to get permissions for:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/User/<userOid>/UserPermissions
```

That collection will have a mix of WorkspacePermission and/or ProjectPermission objects returned in the results depending on the permissions level of the user.